# Why do some Centrino chipsets and PCI-Express cards say Not for Lenovo/HP?

Tags: intel-centrino

I am noticing a bunch of a half-PCI Express Centrino chipsets that say *"not for Lenovo/HP"*, what's the reason for this? Technically, PCI-Express is standardized. What could possibly be different?

Here is [an example,](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-Network-6235AN-HMWWB-Wireless-WiFi-Centrino-Advanced-N-6235-Dual-Band-/200877040597?pt=US_Internal_Network_Cards&hash=item2ec53463d5) and [here is another example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-Centrino-Advanced-N-6230-WiFi-Bluetooth-3-0-Wifi-/140929113648?pt=US_Internal_Network_Cards&hash=item20d0079e30), and [here is another example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-XPS-Advanced-N-6230-Wireless-Card-Bluetooth-13-14z-15-15z-17-L511z-L502X-3-/110995476159?pt=US_Internal_Network_Cards&hash=item19d7d88ebf).

Answer (score 16):

With Lenovo, the problem is that the BIOS has a whitelist of permitted PCI-Express cards and will refuse to boot with any unauthorized PCI card ([source](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card)), i.e., they want you to buy only their own PCI cards. There are often ways around this, including hacking the BIOS, hacking the PCI-Express card (replacing the ID information). If you boot a non-whitelisted card your bios will throw the 1802 error,

> 1802: Unauthorized network card is plugged in - Power off and remove the miniPCI network card.

I suspect the same is true for HP.

Comment: Yea, [it's true for HP](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking-e-g-Windows-8/can-i-put-a-intel-centrion-advanced-n-6230-card-in-my-dv7/td-p/960825). In fact, I'm struggling to find a compatible dual band card for an HP laptop right now...

Answer (score 3):

Lenovo uses a WiFi antenna design that could exceed the maximum radiated power permitted under FCC regulations if used with a card that emitted the maximum power permitted. To avoid a configuration that violates FCC regulations, Lenovo designed the BIOS only to permit WiFi cards that were tested with its antennas to be used.

Comment: Can't all antennas exceed a radiated power with an amplifier and a better method to handle excessive signal-to-noise? I thought it was the card itself that had the transmitter in it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The card itself has the transmitter but not the antenna. The antenna determines the shape of the radiated power. With a high-power transmitter and a high-gain antenna, more power can be radiated in one direction than the FCC permits, theoretically posing a safety hazard if you fall asleep with your head resting on your laptop while you're downloading over WiFi. (These guys are paid to worry about these things.)