# Is there a BIOS hack for the x230 that removes the PCI-Express whitelist?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I understand that some [Lenovo laptops have a white list for approved PCI-Express cards](https://superuser.com/q/563753/11116), is there a way to circumvent this on the x230 with [a BIOS that doesn't implement the whitelist](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card#Modifying_the_BIOS)? There is a forum to request the modification but it's now like [334 pages long.](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/20223-Remove-whitelist-check-add-ID-s-to-break-hardware-restrictions-mod-requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it requires a bit of hardware hacking and is fairly difficult. You can find the [instructions here.](http://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-TUTORIAL-Lenovo-X230-Tablet-BIOS-Whitelist-Removal-Hardware-Flash) You have to have an eeprom programmer, and reasonable solder skills.

That said, you can find a [petition to Lenovo to stop imposing whitelists to achieve vendor lockin.](https://www.change.org/petitions/lenovo-release-an-unencumbered-version-of-the-bios) Please join in combating this restrictive practice.

- https://www.change.org/petitions/lenovo-release-an-unencumbered-version-of-the-bios

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are a few ways to achieve this.

there's a software way, exploiting vulnerabilities in X230 BIOS up to v2.60:
https://github.com/n4ru/1vyrain

you can downgrade your BIOS to this insecure version if needed:
https://github.com/n4ru/IVprep

alternatively refer to this guide: https://github.com/gch1p/thinkpad-bios-software-flashing-guide

There is also a hardware way which replace the stock BIOS by coreboot + seabios and removes the whitelist at the same time. The easiest way to achieve this seems to be skulls: https://github.com/merge/skulls/blob/master/x230/README.md

please note that the BIOS version has to be earlier than v2.77 for this method to work.

If you want to devise your own patch, then reading this 3 part series about unlocking a x230 BIOS will help: https://zmatt.net/unlocking-my-lenovo-laptop-part-1/