# MS-7728 motherboard won't boot with a GT1030 instead of its OEM GT530

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, bios

My [Medion MS-7728](http://msi-ftp.de/Manuals/7728v2.0(Medion).pdf) without integrated graphics won't boot with a [passive Asus GT1030 video card](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GT1030-SL-2G-BRK/) instead of its [OEM GT530](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-530-oem). It shows the boot logo but beeps every 30 seconds and only responds to the power button (short press). [Waiting](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1901502/takes-ages-boot-gtx-770-stuck-bios.html)
    doesn't help (though the monitor does go to and from standby).

This 2012 Medion desktop appears to be using AMI's Aptio 2.14.1219 with BIOS E7728MLN.30F from 04/18/2012 15:58:22, which is more recent than the latest available BIOS from [Medion's website](https://www.medion.com/nl/service/_lightbox/treiber.php?msn=10015140&prod=MEDION%20AKOYA%20P5329%20D%20NL), 2.09 dated 11.01.2012, unpacking image file E7728MLN.209.

Should I install that older BIOS? I fear it will break my [different LAN and USB3](http://msi-ftp.de/Manuals/7728v1.0(Medion).pdf). **Can I back up and restore my installed BIOS using software only?**

Here's my current BIOS info:

[image: MS-7728 BIOS info]

[image: MS-7728 BIOS info CPU-Z]

This older BIOS works just fine with the GT1030 (upgraded from HP GT220) but is in a [2009 HP desktop with MS-7613 v1.0 motherboard](https://support.hp.com/lv-en/document/c01946060):

[image: HP MS-7613 v1.0 info CPU-Z]

Comment: If the new graphics card only supports UEFI (modern) and your motherboard has BIOS firmware (not used for many years) then you are simply out of luck.

Comment: Then why did it show the boot logo via the graphics card?

Comment: Is it getting past the BIOS and to the Windows startup at all? If so, it is likely a driver issue, it is not unusual when changing GPUs that Windows won't boot, but it usually starts to boot.

Comment: I'll try again in 10 hours or so with my old GT220 and no logo to check, also for a whitelist message.

Comment: The MSI GT220 works as well as the MSI GT530. I suspect a vendor lock.

Comment: [Post-2009 HP computers do the same.](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/885573-just-installed-1030-in-old-desktop-and-it-says-bib-1-time-and-then-again-after-a-while/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-MS-7728-Ivy-Bridge-update?pid=139934#pid139934) there exists a `E7728MLN.30G`.

That thread also says the "latest" BIOS I've downloaded from Medion doesn't support my CPU (Ivy Bridge i5 3450), so I won't ([and probably can't](https://community.medion.com/t5/Desktop-PC-All-In-One/geforce-gtx970-kompatibel-mit-mainboard-ms-7728/td-p/6010/page/2)) be installing that. Can't back up the complete BIOS, anyway:

[image: BIOS backup fail]

I could:

1. Try updating the newer PC with an MSI GT1030 (80 euro).
2. Replace the motherboard (40 euro plus possible incompatible
   vendor hardware issues).
3. Simply buy a whole new [non](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/58za48/new_geforce_1060_causes_booting_troubles/)-[Medion](https://community.medion.com/t5/Desktop-PC-All-In-One/Board-MS-7728-2-0-mit-GTX-960/td-p/18079/page/2)
   [computer](https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/pc-booted-nicht-nach-austausch-der-grafikkarten.1726396/). (Nor other brand that locks down hardware.)
4. Try a hacked BIOS which could [brick](https://forum-de.msi.com/index.php?topic=105655.0#) the motherboard if it fails to boot [even with only a USB
   drive](https://service.msicomputer.com/msi_user/support/TechFAQdetail.aspx?formid=3046). Taking a shot at repairing a bricked system is
   [another](https://blah.cloud/hardware/fix-broken-motherboard/)
   [answer](https://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/33904-fix-dead-dual-bios-motherboard-flashing-failed.html) involving specialized skill. **Do not install the [older BIOS](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1901502/takes-ages-boot-gtx-770-stuck-bios.html). The MS-7728 is impossible to restore using software only; even [booting with AMIBIOS.ROM on a boot drive](https://www.bios-mods.com/bios-recovery/ami-bios-recovery/) fails with an "Invalid System Disk" error.**

Answer (score 2):

Cess.

as you wrote in the last post "this post"
There is as a matter of fact a 3.0G bios. and it does infact support the Ivy-bridge cpu.
But it didnt support unapproved graphics cards.

What i did, was to hack together a new bios (took quite some time)
(just uploaded my final version!)

First i updated the intel ME to support the ivy bridge cpu.
This has a huge caveat, you have to use an 8MB bios chip (get a w25q64cv)
[w25q64cv datasheet](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q64cv_revh_052214[2].pdf)

Then i updated the microcode, the memory module for improved memory support
and lastly unlocked the hidden menu.

Then Desolder the old 4MB chip.
Pre-flash the 8MB chip either by hot-flashing in another pc (not recommended) or using a bios chip flasher (a raspberry pi can do it)
[Flashrom for Raspberry pi](https://www.flashrom.org/RaspberryPi)
Solder on a 8 pin socket or solder the chip directly to the board (check the orientation according to the datasheet)

and presto!

It should boot up with the ivy-bridge, be able to support any pci-e gpu, run at least up to 1600 mhz memory (my xeon E5 1225 v2 only supports 1600mhz)
and allocate up to 1024MB ram for the igp if needed.

I can only say its worth it!

[Link to the bioses i've made for the MS-7728](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kKKfnCmKWiKVcNkR4c_bw8iaBFc4wKtV)
[Or use the direct link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y7WwefSXHKkHzlhn2CJ8zS_utZ-UQE_g)

EDIT: i could also flash a chip for you to solder on.
Or alternatively you can send me, your board and i'll do it.

Comment: *Cees, and that's awesome, but i'll live with 40 FPS in Quake Champions until i decide whether to move my new RAM and SSD to the older computer.

Comment: Does my locked BIOS whitelist the vendor, at least, or is an MSI GT 530 the best it supports?

Comment: As stated by the G BIOS source page, it already supports Ivy Bridge.
I could risk buying another GT1030 from MSI (80 euro) or bricking my motherboard (40 euro).

Comment: Argh, major brain fart, It was very late when i wrote that.
I got things mixed up, because i tried to use the 4MB bios at first.
Which i updated the intel ME to 8.1 as required for ivy-bridge (though it wasnt enough)
But i have unlocked that, in terms of the hidden menu and you should be able to use any gpu on that as i set the whitelisting to be off by default in [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fq0D-URyCarsBMKaiu6pPJxt9lB8E-kk/view?usp=sharing)
So if you can live without ivy-bridge, thats the bios to use.

Comment: BTW, you arent going to brick anything as there are spi pins on the motherboard next to the bios chip. infact i have used those to hook an external chip up to.

Comment: Let me be clear: I have a working Ivy Bridge i5 but the 8 MB BIOS with 3 MB image (E7728MLN.30F) does not support my new non-MSI GPU. The only BIOS image offered by Medion is for a non-applicable version of my MS-7728.
Is 30G an official BIOS that meets and exceeds 30F?

Comment: Note that any hardware actions beyond replacing a BIOS battery are not worth my time.

Comment: Ah, now i get it.
well the 3.0G bios is official [link](http://cdn.medion.com/downloads/treiber/bio7728v3.exe) direct link to medion
So dont worry about my 3.0G bios it will run :)

Comment: I'm just confused as to why their website doesn't appear to link to that. Btw, searching for "ms-7728" there now only gives me 2.09 (E7728MLN.209) and [4.0E (M7728W08.40E)](https://www.medion.com/nl/service/_lightbox/treiber_details.php?did=12218) - Is that better than and backwards compatible with 3.0G (E7728MLN.30G)?

Comment: The 4.0E, as far as i've tested is a beta and cant boot from any device, it will post though. It seemed further evolved compared to 3.0G except for the boot problem.

Comment: Your direct linked BIOS did not solve the problem.

Comment: Ill be damned. Ill look into it soon :-)

Comment: Any luck? I couldn't find it either.